# Ubuntu GDK C++ how to get the code of a key using CAPSLOCK

Tags: c++, ubuntu, keycode, gdk, capslock

In Ubuntu C++ I use *gdk_keymap_get_entries_for_keycode*() to get the keyval of a key. This works well for all keys with my shiftstates:

If I pass

- keycode 38, shiftstate 0 into *gdk_keymap_get_entries_for_keycode*() I get *keyvals[0] = 97  (=a)
- keycode 38, shiftstate 1 into *gdk_keymap_get_entries_for_keycode*() I get *keyvals[1] = 65  (=A)

Now I want to take the capslock into consideration as well. So I want to get the following results:

- keycode 38, shiftstate 0, Caps 0   =>  I want to get: 97  (=a)
- keycode 38, shiftstate 1, Caps 0   =>  I want to get: 65  (=A)
- keycode 38, shiftstate 0, Caps 1   =>  I want to get: 65  (=A)
- keycode 38, shiftstate 1, Caps 1   =>  I want to get: 97  (=a)

I know Can I determine the capslock-state with gdk_keymap_get_caps_lock_state() but

**how can I use this state to find the appropriate code of a character**?

Comment: First: There is no Ubuntu C++. I guess you refer to the C API of GTK. Second: you have to write the code by your own. The caps lock is reversing the meaning of shift. There is no extra entry for caps lock + shift.